# How do I call a touchesBegan function?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I simply want to make the position of "mainBall" the position of the touch. How can I call the `touchesBegan` function?, if i create a override function with `touchesBegan` outside of the "override function `didMoveToView`(view: SKView) then it cant access the "mainBall" "SKSpriteNode" and its location because it is inside `didMoveToView`. I am puzzled, any help is much appreciated in advanced.

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

let MainBallCategoryName = "mainBall"

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)

    var mainBall = childNodeWithName(MainBallCategoryName) as SKSpriteNode

    println(mainBall.position)


func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        mainBall.position = location


      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call the `touchesBegan`-method by yourself. That does Swift for you. Also you have to move the method outside of your `didMoveToView` method. You can't nest a function inside another function:

So you have to do something like that:

```
let MainBallCategoryName = "mainBall"

class GameScene: SKScene {
    //Make your ball to a global variable to access it in your 'touchesBegan' method
    var mainBall:SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)

        var circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)

        mainBall = SKSpriteNode()
        mainBall.name = MainBallCategoryName
        mainBall.addChild(circle)

        println(mainBall.position)

    }

    //Add the 'override' to your method
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            mainBall.position = location


        }
    }
}
```

As you see, I've added the `override` to your `touchesBegan` method. That's important because that way Swift knows "Oh he want to handle a touch by himself". Also I've moved the `mainBall` variable outside of your `didMoveToView` method. Because that way you can access it in your `touchesBegan` method.

Comment: It looks great, but when I touch the screen I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" right away.

Comment: I think the problem is with `childNodeWithName`. I will update my answer and make a proper SKSpriteNode for you.

Comment: I've edited it. You should make a ball either with an SKTexture or an SKShapeNode.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I don't get the error anymore. Should I see a circle with a radius of 10? nothing moves when touched.

Comment: You need to add the ball to your scene: addChild(mainBall)

Comment: I noticed that now when it "println(mainBall.position)" it is (0.0,0.0) unlike before.

Comment: I added it in GameScene.sks, should I add it a different way?

Comment: also you need to set the position: mainBall.position = CGPointMake(200, 100)

Comment: .sks files are SpriteKit's equivalent of .xib files. You're creating your nodes in code, so no need to also add them to the .sks file.

Comment: Also, you haven't set a color for either of your nodes, so they default to transparent. Try adding a `fillColor` to your shape node.

Comment: It worked, I got a small blue color filled circle to follow where I touch! Now I made the "var circle" a SKTexture to get the image I originally wanted, but it says that "'SKTexture' is not convertible to 'SkNode'" at "mainBall.addChild(circle)".

Comment: I removed the "mainBall.addChild(circle)" and the var circle lines, then added mainBall.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "main circle.png") and got nothing, why is that?

Comment: When you say global variable, mainBall isn't actually global, it belongs separately to each instance of GameScene. The variable MainBallCategoryName is global since it can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: How would I be able to access my custom Color Sprites I added in my GameScene.sks anywhere in my GameScene.swift?